# $X$ be a connected metric space and $F$ be subring of $C(X,\Bbb{R})$ which is a field. Then every element of $F$ is constant. (T/F)

Tags: real-analysis, ring-theory, metric-spaces, connectedness

This is a True/False question. Here $C(X,\Bbb{R})$ is the ring of all real valued continuous function on $X$. I can prove if $F$ is finite then it is true.

In that case, we have $n$ such that $f^n=1$, then using connectivity of $X$ we are done.

But I don't know about infinite such $F$.

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: *Hint*. Clearly $1\in F$. Now, let $f \in F$ and suppose there exist $a, b \in X$ such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. Then consider the function $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{f(a) - f(b)} \in F$$ and study whether there exists $h \in F$ such that $g(x)h(x) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks I got it. $g(b)=0$ so it cannot have inverse, which is a contradiction

Comment: Great work! Anyway, now that this argument does not use connectivity of $X$ at all, I wonder why this condition was included in the problem...

Comment: I think the reason is just a semantic difference. For some authors, a subring does not require to preserve the unit (and so $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ will be a subring). For instance, if $X$ has two connected componets $A$ and $B$, the set of fuctions of the form $\lambda \cdot 1_A$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ forms a subring which is also a field, but is definitely not made of constant functions.

Comment: Now, if $R \subset C(X, \mathbb{R})$ is a subring which is also a field, and $f$ is the unit of $R$, then $f^2=f$, and so $f(x)=0, 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. As $f$ is not the zero function, then $f$ is equal to the constant function $1$, as $X$ is connected.

Comment: This way, if $g \in R$ is nonzero, then $g\cdot h$ is equal to the constant function $1$, where $h$ is its inverse in $R$. At the end, we get that $h(x)=1/g(x)$ pointwise, which was not necessarily true!

Comment: @NicolásVilches, That makes sense!

Comment: Why F contains all constant functions?

Comment: @SangchulLee Could you explain why $g\in F$? Are all constant functions in $F$?

Comment: @ZSMJ, That is a valid objection which I completely overlooked. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. The answer is clearly negative (as we can see in the example $F=\{r\cdot\mathbf{1}:r\in\mathbb{Q}\}$), and the proof strategy must be modified. I wrote down an answer addressing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will adopt the usual definition that a ring contains a multiplicative identity and that a subring must inherit the same identity as its super-ring.

Note that the constant function $\mathbf{1}$ lies in $F$. Since $F$ is a field characteristic zero, for any $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, the constant function $r \cdot \mathbf{1}$ lies in $F$ as well.

Now assume that $F$ contains a non-constant function $f$, and let $a, b \in X$ be such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. Then we can find two rational numbers, $r$ and $s$, such that

$$ r f(a) + s < 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad r f(b) + s > 0. $$

Now let

$$g(x) = r f(x) + s.$$

Then $g(X)$ is a connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ that contains both positive and negative numbers, and so, $g$ must attain the value $0$ by the intermediate value theorem. This shows that $g$ is a non-zero element of $F$ That does not have a multiplicative inverse, contradicting the assumption on $F$ being a field. Therefore $F$ can only contain constant functions.